# How to convert select_related queries in Django into a single dataframe

Tags: django, pandas

I am working in Django and I would like to simply merge three tables into one dataset. My models look like so and I have tried variants of the following command:

```
class Quadrat(models.Model):
  quadrat_number = models.IntegerField()


class Capture(models.Model):
   quadrat= models.ForeignKey(Quadrat, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
   capture_total = models.IntegerField()

class Species(models.Model):
     capture = models.ForeignKey(Capture, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
     species = models.CharField(max_length=50)


data = pd.DataFrame(list(Species.objects.select_related('Capture_set', 'Quadrat_set').all()
```

I get an attribute error: Cannot find 'Capture_set' on Species object, 'Capture_set' is an invalid parameter to select_related()

I am probably using select_related wrong.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can not perform a `select_related` on a one-to-many or many-to-many relation, since that could result in *huge* result sets, you can only `prefetch_relate` these.

Comment: Well seen, but I havent had much luck with prefetch_related either: dataframe has no attribute 'species'